# How to publish react app in correct way with gh-pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I've deployed my react app to `Github` and I'm facing an error that my app isn't rendered on the page

The Message Of The Console

[image]

This is my `package.json` file

[image]

This is my HTML file

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try following this [tutorial](https://dev.to/yuribenjamin/how-to-deploy-react-app-in-github-pages-2a1f) to ensure you completed all the required steps for deploying a React app and hosting it on gh pages. Please ask if you face any issues.

Comment: I found this command ""deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build"" in react app tutorial and when I replace it everything goes well but I can't understand the difference and why this work and the other not